# Python: Не получается отловить событие изменения окна

Tags: python, windows, gui, tkinter

Не удаётся правильно обработать событие изменения размеров окна. В данной программе виджеты должны подгоняться под размер окна. topFrame должен принимать ширину по ширине окна, а leftFrame и rightFrame должны принимать половину от ширины окна и высоту равную высоте окна-высота topFrame. При этом если я изменяю окно по ширине т.е. тяну за левый либо правый край окна то виджеты "реагируют" и изменяют ширину, а вот если пытаюсь тоже самое проделать с высотой - показывают кукиш.

Python 2.7, Windows 7
[Код тут (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/EycLwLZ0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените две строки:

```
#app = Application()
app = Application(root)
```

и

```
#app.bind('<Configure>',resizeFrames)
root.bind('<Configure>',resizeFrames)
```

---

для работы достаточно второй замены, но раз уж используете

```
def __init__(self, master=root):
```

то лучше передавайте этот root.

И ещё, у меня по умолчанию открылось с минимальной шириной, я не знаю как вы задумываете, поэтому просто скажу об этом=)

Comment: да ширина маленькая, попробовал передать root однако результат тот-же. И еще я заметил что если растягивать окно вверх, за верхний край то событие обрабатывается

Comment: так замена не помогла?

Comment: Всё, с обоими заменами всё работает отлично! Сбасибо! Не могу плюсануть ибо репа низкая :(

Comment: Ничего, думаю ещё встретимся))